# why my code change not pushed to remote branch

Tags: git, branch

I made some changes to a cpp file, say test.cpp when I work in my master branch. Then I push it to a remote branch so that I can pull request later:

```
git add test.cpp
git commit -m "blabla"
git push origin master:remoteBranchName(non-master branch)
```

Then I checked that remote branch, but I saw no code change. I mean, what I changed to my master branch is not shown in the remote branch.

Then I use `git log` to show commit history, but it does not show my newest commit.

**Solved**
I finally found that, this problem arises because I made changes in vs. But vs open the project in a different folder(I keep two versions of the project in two folders). Because I start vs from a script(not written by me; project path specified in the script), so I did not notice it. So now it's clear that I change my code in one project, but I pushed another...
Well, thank you for helping me locating the problem.

Comment: Try git push -u origin master

Comment: @JeetendraChoudhary I think this command will push things to remote master, while I do not think I have the privilege. I want to push my master to a remote non-master branch and then pull request.

Answer (score 0):

> Then I checked that remote branch

If you check locally, you would not see it.
Similarly, a `git log` is local only: you would need a `git fetch` first, and `git log origin/remoteBranchName` to actually check those latest commits are indeed there.

You need to check the remote repo through its web interface (like GitHub proposes), making sure you select the `remoteBranchName` (those web interfaces often display `master` by default)

More generally, you need to check the source and destination of your push.
As the OP noted:

> I change my code in one project, but I pushed another...

Comment: I checked the remote branch through web interface, and I did choose that very branch, but I didn't see the change I want.

Comment: @dudu do you see your changes locally on master? (git log master)

Comment: I followed your advice. Use `git fetch` and `git log origin/remoteBranchName`, but it does not show my latest commit, even though I have tried staging and committing again.

Comment: Yes, that's why I think the whole thing is strange. I can see the changes locally on master.

Comment: @dudu What git status return?

Comment: @dudu if you try again a `git push origin master:remoteBranchName`, what is the output?

Comment: `git status` just reminds me that my master branch is "behind `origin master` by 2 commits, and can be fast-forward." and it lists untracked files. `git push origin master:remoteBranchName` again tells me: "Everything up-to-date".

Comment: What is origin? `git remote -v`: does it reference the repo you think it does?

Comment: Yes, the right repo. I think there must be some "tiny thing" wrong. But I don't know where.

Comment: @dudu is remoteBranchName a new branch? Dies it start from master?

Comment: @dudu Also could you simply try and push to a new not-yet-create remote branch? And make your PR from that newly created remote branch?

Comment: @remoteBranchName is a new branch. I find one thing really strange. When I work in master branch, I made changes under vs. Yeah, in vs I can also see the changes, including closing it and reopening. However, in git bash, I cannot see the code changes with vim. I think you are right. I have not successfully made the changes locally in my master branch.

Comment: remoteBranchName is a new branch. I find one thing really strange. When I work in master branch, I made changes under vs. Yeah, in vs I can also see the changes, including closing it and reopening. However, in git bash, I cannot see the code changes with vim. I think you are right. I have not successfully made the changes locally in my master branch.

Comment: @dudu try and fall back to command line in order to git add and git commit to the master branch.

Comment: @dudu I have edited the answer to include the more generic advice for this type of situation.